# How can I prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\log n-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k^2+1}\right)>0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\qquad$I wondered if it's possible to prove the following fact :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\log n-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k^2+1}\right)>0,$$
without numerical calculations.

**My attempt :** By means of this familiar conclusion
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\log n\right),$$
I've got the limit equals to
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3+n}-\gamma=0.09465\cdots.$$
$\qquad$Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Actually you've done all. The last line you wrote is equivalent to the limit in the first line.

Comment: Oh, yes. Due to carelessness, I failed to pay attention to the last step. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^2+1}, \quad H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k},$$ so that $$H_n - f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \frac{k}{k^2+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^3 + k}.$$  Then $$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \log n - f(n) \right) 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\log n - H_n + H_n - f(n)\right) \\
&= -\lim_{n \to \infty} (H_n - \log n) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^3 + k} \\
&= -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3 + k} \\
&> -\gamma + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{10} \\
&= \frac{3}{5} - \gamma.
\end{align}$$
Then all that remains is to show that $\gamma < 0.6$.  If we take its value $\gamma \approx 0.57721566490 \ldots$ for granted, then the result is proven.  If we do not, then you would have to establish a suitable upper bound.

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't notice the last step.